# EJ030NA-05B to hdmi

Tags: lcd, hdmi

I recovered a printer display that seems to belong to the same family as EJ030NA-01B but I am unable to find the exact datasheet and the connector is way to tiny to match a 40 pin to HDMI converting card even if the connection cable is marked as having 39 pins. Here is the display and his old connector (I'm a beginner so I may have made incredibly obvious mistakes ) :[image: front]
[image: back]
[image: old board where it was connected]

Comment: So what's your question? Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: You need to first find a datasheet for the LCD to figure out what kind of bus it has before you can start to figure out if it is even possible to connect it to HDMI receiver. Besides you can't buy chips with content protection so it would be very small and limited to unprotected content.

Comment: This datasheet is an LED backlit digital 800x600 x 24 bit display with HS and VSync and analog bias for the LCD.  Do you need to learn how to use this? Yes. Lots of reading beyond the datasheet https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/788926/Innolux/EJ080NA-05B/1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, I have already seen the datasheet you sent me and thought it was not the exact same LCD ( J080 instead ou J030 ) but if it is the same I trust you. So I just need to find the right board that convert this bus to HDMI with the specified connector manufactured by Hirose (or equivalent ) ?